# Microsoft Excel - Shift-Up, Shift-Down like Google Sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

**In Google Sheets, I can modify a selection by using the keyboard shortcuts:**

- Shift + Arrow Keys
- And similarly: Shift + Page Up/Down

I have grown very used to this.

Unfortunately, this only works sometimes in Microsoft Excel.

**An example of when it does not work:**

1. Click on cell D4
2. Hold Shift
3. Press Arrow Keys

**Is there an easy-to-use alternative within Microsoft Excel?**

Comment: What do you mead by modify a selection?

Comment: Holding Shift and using arrow or page keys to adjust the selected area is standard Windows behavior - Excel does it, Word does it, File Explorer does it, Google Chrome does it. I can't think of any reason you'd have trouble with it in Excel specifically. Can you reproduce the misbehavior in any other application?

Comment: @T.J.L.(1) Open Excel, (2) New blank workbook, (3) Click cell C3, (4) Press Shift-Down  --- no expansion of selection.

@ReddyLutonadio I mean expansion/contraction in various directions depending upon the arrows.

Comment: You mean like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xET5b.gif)?

Comment: @BrianWebster Yes. As I said, SHIFT-Selection is standard Windows user interface behavior . It is nothing Excel-specific, and it works just fine in Excel for everybody else. You didn't answer the question I asked: Can you *reproduce the misbehavior* in *any other application*?

Comment: @T.J.L.The technique works fine on tables in MS Word, works fine in Google Sheets, but not MS Excel